# passing std::future to a boost::thread vs a std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future, boost-thread

I cant seem to figure out why the following code compiles with std::thread,
but not with boost::thread,gives the following error on msvs 2015.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C2280   'std::future::future(const std::future &)':
> attempting to reference a deleted function

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
void threadFunction(std::future<void> futureObj)
{
    std::cout << "Thread Start" << std::endl;
    while (futureObj.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        std::cout << "Doing Some Work" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
    std::cout << "Thread End" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    // Create a std::promise object
    std::promise<void> exitSignal;
    //Fetch std::future object associated with promise
    std::future<void> futureObj = exitSignal.get_future();
    // Starting Thread & move the future object in lambda function by reference
    std::thread th(&threadFunction, std::move(futureObj));
    //boost::thread th(&threadFunction, std::move(futureObj));//this gives error
    //Wait for 10 sec
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << "Asking Thread to Stop" << std::endl;
    //Set the value in promise
    exitSignal.set_value();
    //Wait for thread to join
    th.join();
    std::cout << "Exiting Main Function" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `boost::thread`'s `(function, args)` constructor is specified as

> As if `thread(boost::bind(f,a1,a2,...))`

and `boost::bind` copies arguments instead of moving them when calling the underlying function (because it has to allow multiple calls).

Why is it this way? Possibly due to backwards-compatibility with pre-move Boost.Thread versions.

`std::thread` has no such restriction and specifies that the arguments are moved.

Comment: so what should i do to make it work? std::move isint sufficient? i tried with boost::ref/std::ref everything..

Comment: @ashishsony You could try sending a `shared_future` instead? Is that still a thing? I'm not fully up-to-date on C++. The performance penalty ought to be negligible compared to starting a new thread.

Comment: Thanks, std::shared_future works with boost::thread